# Execution flow in Python

Tags: python, luigi

I am using Python3.4 Luigi pipeline that interacts with Linux terminal, and I need to take user input. I have the code that looks something like below:

```
test = input("Enter data: ")
logger.info(test)

Class One{...}
Class Two{...}
Class Three{...}
```

I would expect the terminal to not print anything after `"Enter data: "` , but it keeps updating the terminal with debug info (i.e. Asking scheduler for work, pending Class One to finish), so the users cannot enter inputs. Is there any way to prevent the terminal from printing until it takes the user input?

Thanks

## UPDATE

It seems that class One is executed even though user does not enter input. I am not sure why this is happening,.,,

Comment: if you have some "class elements" in class, not in its methods, then it will be executed at start when file is loaded. So show your class.

Comment: It sounds like Luigi is redirecting Python's input to the pipe, so it's not connected to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have separate files for your script and your tasks and trigger the main task this way. The idea is to read user input and if it's not empty then you run the desired task.

```
import luigi
from my_tasks import MyTask

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = input("Enter data: ")
    if test:
        luigi.build([MyTask1(123, "foobar")], local_scheduler=False)
```

There's at least another way to instantiate and run a Luigi Task programmatically that you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118730/3219121).